# C Database Design, Sortable by Multiple Fields

Tags: c, database, performance, sorting

If memory is not an issue for my particular application (entry, lookup, and sort speed being the priorities), what kind of data structure/concept would be the best option for a multi-field rankings table?

For example, let's say I want to create a Hall of Fame for a game, sortable by top score (independent of username), username (with all scores by the same user placed together before ranking users by their highest scores), or level reached (independent of score or name).  In this example, if I order a linked list, vector, or any other sequential data structure by the top score of each player, it makes searching for the other fields -- like level and non-highest scores -- more iterative (i.e. iterate across all looking for the stage, or looking for a specific score-range), unless I conceive some other way to store the information sorted when I enter new data.

The question is whether there is a more efficient (albeit complicated and memory-consumptive) method or database structure in C/C++ that might be primed for this kind of multi-field sort.  Linked lists seem fine for simple score rankings, and I could even organize a hashtable by hashing on a single field (player name, or level reached) to sort by a single field, but then the other fields take O(N) to find, worse to sort.  With just three fields, I wonder if there is a way (like sets or secondary lists) to prevent iterating in certain pre-desired sorts that we know beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it the same way databases do it: using index structures. You have your main data as a number of records (structs), perhaps ordered according to one of your sorting criteria. Then you have index structures, each one ordered according to one of your other sorting criteria, but these index structures don't contain copies of all the data, just pointers to the main data records. (Think "index" like the index in a book, with page numbers "pointing" into the main data body.)

Using ordered linked list for your index structures will give you a fast and simple way to go through the records in order, but it will be slow if you need to search for a given value, and similarly slow when inserting new data.

Hash tables will have fast search and insertion, but (with normal hash tables) won't help you with ordering at all.

So I suggest some sort of tree structure. Balanced binary trees (look for AVL trees) work well in main memory.

But don't forget the option to use an actual database! Database managers such as MySQL and SQLite can be linked with your program, without a separate server, and let you do all your sorting and indexing very easily, using SQL embedded in your program. It will probably execute a bit slower than if you hand-craft your own main-memory data structures, or if you use main-memory data structures from a library, but it might be easier to code, and you won't need to write separate code to save the data on disk.

Comment: Thanks for the great advice! I feel like, since there are such a large number of names, and grouping scores by name is an important feature, I might want to hash by names, but keep the scores under each name always-sorted.  Is it bad design form to have pointers at each player node, pointing to the next highest-scoring player, as a way to keep players ranked by their high scores?  Finally, in response to your indexing suggestion -- given that displaying results is the most common operation, do you think it is worthwhile to keep the index structures always-sorted?  Would you use trees for them?

Answer (score 2):

So, you already know how to store your data and keep it sorted with respect to a single field. Assuming the values of the fields for a single entry are independent, the only way you'll be able to get what you want is to keep three different lists (using the data structure of your choice), each of which are sorted to a different field. You'll use three times the memory's worth of pointers of a single list.

As for what data structure each of the lists should be, using a [binary max heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) will be effective. Insertion is lg(N), and displaying individual entries in order is O(1) (so O(N) to see all of them). If in some of these list copies the entries need to be sub-sorted by another field, just consider that in the comparison function call.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Yes, it seems like additional pointer memory is the best case scenario (since copying the actual data would make management & maintenance a major pain).  I get what you're saying about the subfields -- like if we always want to use score to rank people within categories, like level reached, or entries grouped by player.  Would you use the same data structure for all your lists?  Like, if there were 100000+ names, but only 100 possible levels, maybe you hashmap the names ranking but use the binary heap for levels?  Just a random thought..